# I need alternative solutions to swfobject.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flash

I have a quite old website using swfobject.js to play .mp3 files by generating  .swf files at run time.

As major browsers are not support Flash natively, I need recommendations to swap swfobject.js to other available libraries that's able to play .mp3 at run time.

Is there any good solution allowing me to replace swfobject.js from my website to completely remove Flash without too much pain!

Thanks!

Stonez

Answer (score 3):

All popular browsers now [support MP3 natively](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mp3) via the `<audio>` element (which is [similarly well supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=audio)). No plugins or workarounds are required, and the element [can be controlled via JavaScript usin the `HTMLMediaElement` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio).

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer! I will look into it.